# I can't fill a pdf template with data

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext, pdfbox

<s>I have some data which I want to save in a pdf file. I don't want to create a pdf from source code. A client gives me many different templates and I want to fill these with data which he needs. For example I have an information about "name", "surname", "address", "phone number" etc. A client gives me a template where there are columns only for "name", "surname", he doesn't care about "address" and "phone number".</s>

I've tried something like this(from: [Creating complex pdf using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14151335/creating-complex-pdf-using-java))

```
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("C:/folder/template/template.pdf");
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("C:/folder/template/filledTemplate.pdf"));
    AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();

    boolean column = form.setField("column", "insert data");
    boolean key = form.setField("key", "insert key");
    boolean value = form.setField("value", "insert value");

    stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
```

The problem is it doesn't do anything. A form variable is null. I don't have any requirements about tools. It doesn't need to be itext, It can be PDFBox(which I haven't used yet).
Example pdf file: 
[pdf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGgR7.png)

**Edit:**
I've just asked my colleague about this. Sorry for my mistake, we have some data in our application and I'm doing a converter to various types of files like excel or pdf. 
We have many columns so there's no problem with excel files but I can't put all data in pdf. 
So one of the solution is a client would choose a specific form of pdf with columns which he needs and he gets a pdf filled with data. So wee need different templates.

Comment: You should share the PDF instead of a screen shot of the PDF. You are using code that requires the PDF to be a form. Looking at the screen shot, I don't see a form. I can't test if the PDF is interactive. For instance: if you open the PDF in Adobe Reader and you click on a cell in the table, can you add content to that cell? If not, your so-called template isn't a form.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I can't add content to any cell(in AR). I thought I could just create a table with headers and it could be filled by a java program.

Comment: When you say you *could just create a table with headers and it could be filled by a Java program*, it isn't clear what you mean. That sounds as if you want to create the PDF from scratch, which is in contradication with what you write in your question.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I've created a pdf (for tests) with a table because I don't have any templates from clients yet.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie so is it possible to get a pdf template with a table and fill it by my program or I have to create pdf from source code?

Comment: PDF is not quite easy as template. Something like **JasperReports** might be more suited. But first an actual scenario is missing for me dummy. The clients give PDF templates? Or forms? And data are filled in, per client somewhat differently?

Comment: Yes and no. There is no clear answer to your question because you aren't asking us a clear question. You don't have sufficient knowledge about AcroForm technology versus the XML Forms Architecture (XFA). As @JoopEggen explains: we don't know anything about the scenario. This is not an invitation to post a scenario as a question. Such a question would immediately be closed as "Too broad." It's an invitation for you to start getting an education about form technology.

Comment: @steeve Please be aware that a table in a PDF usually is merely a collection of lines or rectangles and some text fragments. It is **not** a table object as such anymore which one can *select* and *fill*. If you want to **fill** some such table cells, you should put an AcroForm form field there to fill in and probably flatten after the fact. Other agreed-upon annotations may give rise to a solution, too.

Comment: Using an AcroForm for this type of job isn't a good idea. XFA could be a solution, but it's too complex for most users, it requires buying Adobe LiveCycle Designer, and on top of that all, XFA will be deprecated in PDF 2.0 (ISO-32000-2). I would suggest that you ask your customers to create a simple HTML and CSS file, that you populate the HTML with  data, and use iText's XML worker to create the PDF.