# Unable to set Field Values using acrofields for form in Ms Word

Tags: java, pdf, itext, acrofields

I am trying to make a fillable pdf in Ms Word by providing forms like textField as explained [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-fillable-form-39a58412-107e-426b-a10b-ac44937e3a9f). Next i am trying to change the values of the form field as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14151335/creating-complex-pdf-using-java).
However when i try it the values don't change and also the `form.getFields().values()` gives an empty array.
I have added the bookmarks to each field but still it gives no change in values.
Am i missing something?
Below is my tried code:

```
PdfReader reader = new  PdfReader(PATH);
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader,new FileOutputStream(newPATH));
AcroFields form = pdfStamper.getAcroFields();
System.out.println(form.getFields().values());
form.setField("Seller Info","Some Text");
form.setField("Buyer Info","Some Text");
form.setField("NoOfBundles", "3");
form.setField("InvoiceDate","2019/04/22");
pdfStamper.setFormFlattening(true);
pdfStamper.close();
reader.close();
```

This is the fillable pdf i am trying to create: 
[file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jWC9K1cyXI_uVf_BBmlPRsOxGJaoIOqg)
Thanks.

Comment: as per this code, you are just reading a PDF and setting the values to the fields

Comment: yes thats what i want to do..set the values to the fields dynamically.

Comment: the problem is the values are not getting set to the fields in the modified pdf

Comment: you want the name of the fields? and want to replace?

Comment: no..i need to add values  to the fields

Comment: e.g if there is a textbox filed named 'address' then i need to add some value like "Grand Trunk Road" in that textbox field

Comment: I feel like the name of the fields are different

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192311/discussion-between-pranay-and-danyal-sandeelo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much of googling,i tried using Open Office and by adding `fields.setGenerateApperances(true)` it worked as expected!
Also while exporting as pdf we need to select `Create pdf` form and select `FDF` as the submit form.